# Google Script App Delete Duplicate Rows but Keep one with Specific Status

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am looking at this posting here and it is closely along the lines of what I am trying to do for my project. How would I change this to make it work like the following:

I have data in columns A thru P on sheet "Test Sheet". Column P provides the "DisputeStatus". The status can be one of three statuses: NULL, PENDING, or APPROVED. New data is being added to the bottom of the rows each day. Duplicates are only created when new data is added to the bottom each day and the "DisputeStatus" of a previously recorded line item above has changed. So, I would now have 2 rows with the exact same data in columns A thru O but in column P (the "DisputeStatus") it would be different with one row saying PENDING and the other row saying APPROVED. I want to find the duplicates and then delete only the duplicates with the "old priority" status and keep the duplicate row with the "new priority" status.

For Example:

The following status priority sets are the possible duplicated rows with different "DisputeStatus" in column P:

```
NULL (old)(delete)
PENDING (new)(keep)


PENDING (old)(delete)
APPROVED (new)(keep)


PENDING (old)(delete)
DENIED (new)(keep)

function removeDuplicates()
{
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Test Sheet");
  var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  var indexOfStatusColumn = 16;
  var newData = [];
  data.forEach(function (row, rowI){
    var isDuplicate = false
    if (newData.length)
    newData.forEach(function (dup, dupI)
    {
      if (dup[3] == row[3])
      {
        if (row[indexOfStatusColumn] == "APPROVED" && dup[indexOfStatusColumn] != "APPROVED")
          newData[dupI][indexOfStatusColumn] = "APPROVED";
        isDuplicate = true;
        return (false);
      }
    })
    if (!isDuplicate)
      newData.push(row);
  });
  dataRange = sheet.getRange(2, 1, dataRange.getLastRow() - 1, dataRange.getLastColumn());
  dataRange.clearContent();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, newData.length, newData[0].length).setValues(newData);
}
```

Comment: "I am looking at this posting here and it is closely along the lines of what I am trying to do for my project." Please provide a link to the post.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the full working code to remove the duplicates as you explained. It will make an array of the row positions to delete (The ones that fulfill the conditions) and after the loops it will delete those duplicate rows.

```
function removeDuplicates() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Test Sheet");
  var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  data.shift();
  var indexOfStatusColumn = 16;
  var rowsDelete = [];

  data.forEach(function (row, rowI){
    data.forEach(function (row2, row2I) {

      if (row2[3] == row[3]) {
        if ((row[indexOfStatusColumn] == "APPROVED" && row2[indexOfStatusColumn] != "APPROVED") || (row[indexOfStatusColumn] == "PENDING" && row2[indexOfStatusColumn] == "NULL")) {
          var rowNum = Number(row2I + 2);          
          if (rowsDelete.indexOf(rowNum) == -1) {
            rowsDelete.push(rowNum);
          }
        }
      }
    })

  });

  rowsDelete.sort(function(a, b){return b-a});    // Sort the numbers in the array in descending order
  rowsDelete.forEach(function (rowNum, rowI){
    sheet.deleteRow(rowNum);  //Delete rows
  })
}
```

Comment: Hello, this script keeps the entire page unchanged.  Good news is no errors popping up.

Comment: The code is making the comparison of duplicates with the D column. Change the indexOfStatusColumn equal to 15 if you have your statuses in column P (i thought it was in Q)